# Miscrosoft Access - Multi-Table Data Entry

Tags: microsoft-access, database

I'm using Microsoft Access 2016, and am designing a tool to track our engineer drawings at work.  As you can see from the image of my relationships, the project info cascades down on the left and the drawing info cascades down on the right, and meets in a junction table in the center.  My problem is this:

How do I create a form that will allow my users to add a specific drawing revision to a specific IFC, and hopefully also allow them to create new drawings with a revision at the same time?  I've looked everywhere and just get more and more confused every time I read about sub-forms.  Do I need queries here?  Does this need to be multiple forms?

Relationship Design:

[image]

Comment: Yes, subforms can help you achieve this.